# How to filter datetime (POSIXct) in a df, where each datetime is repeated multiple times

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, filter, posixct

I am trying to filter a df by date (POSIXct). In this df, each date is repeated 13 times. I have tried various ways, but the result is an empty df, unless I specify a long date_time interval (e.g. 1 year). If I use a long date_time interval, the df has data but it is not consistent with the date_time interval!!!

```
|DateXct            | sectname| Dist_m |TempAdj_C|
|:----------------- |:-------:|:------:|--------:|
|2022-12-16 16:30:06|   W1    |29.13   |24.1514  |
|2022-12-16 16:30:06|   W1    |30.14   |24.2424  |
|2022-12-16 16:30:06|   W1    |31.15   |24.2242  |
|.                  |         |        |         |
|.                  |         |        |         |
|. 13 times         |         |        |         |
|2022-12-16 16:37:40|   W1    |29.13   |24.1514  |
|2022-12-16 16:37:40|   W1    |30.14   |24.2515  |
|2022-12-16 16:37:40|   W1    |31.15   |24.2424  |
|2022-12-16 16:37:40|   W1    |32.17   |24.2697  |
|.                  |         |        |         |
|.                  |         |        |         |
|. 13 times         |         |        |         |
```

I have used filter function:

```
dftest <- df %>%
   filter(DateXct > '2022-12-16 16:30:06' & DateXct < '2022-12-16 16:52:45')
```

Also, "filter" and "between" functions (with and without "as.POSIXct" and "format" functions):

```
dftest <- df %>%
  filter(between(DateXct, as.POSIXct('2022-12-17 02:11:26', format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), as.POSIXct('2022-12-16 16:52:45', format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
```

Function subset:

```
subset(df, DateXct> "2022-12-16 16:30:06" & DateXct < "2022-12-16 16:52:45")
```

Another option:

```
df[(df$DateXct> "2022-12-16 16:30:06" & df$DateXct < "2022-12-16 16:52:45"),]
```

My new df (dftest) is always empty

Comment: To filter for a date, you need the conditions to be date `class`. For example, `dftest <- df %>% filter(DateXct > as.POSIXct('2022-12-16 16:30:06') & DateXct < as.POSIXct('2022-12-16 16:52:45'))`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue with the time zones. If I use the RStudio console to request a datetime of any df row, the result shows the time in UTC time zone:

> dftest$DateXct[1]
> [1] "2022-12-16 16:37:40 UTC"

But if I create a date time variable, I get the datetime in AEST time zone:

> initDate <- as.POSIXct('2022-12-16 16:37:40')
> initDate
> [1] "2022-12-16 16:37:40 AEST"

So, to make the datetime interval work, I need to add 36000 s (10 hr) to my datetime filter line:
dftest <- df %>%
filter(DateXct >= as.POSIXct('2022-12-16 16:37:40')+36000 & DateXct <= as.POSIXct('2022-12-16 17:00:18')+36000)

Any idea how to make time zones uniform for any R operation??